# Does an index with collection group scope cover queries made on a single collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Does an index with a collection group scope also enable queries on a single collection? The [documentation of query scope](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/Shared.Types/QueryScope) is ambiguous to me. I need to run the same query requiring a composite index on both a single collection and collection group and am unsure whether I need two indexes (one for each scope) or a single index with a collection group scope.

Comment: You can find out for sure by just making a collection group query index, then see if it satisfies the query you're trying to perform.  You'll see a clear error about needing to create an index if it's not working.  My guess is that the two scopes are completely different and indexes on one will not affect the other.